# shell command `tmux` throws `can't use /dev/tty` error

Tags: bash, tmux, terminal-emulator, fish, termite

I just switched from using terminator to termite today. I also Installed Fish and `oh my fish,` Spent a couple hours configuring  everything, but when I went to start a tmux session to get some work done it returned `open terminal failed: can't use /dev/tty`.

I set Fish to my default shell. tmux works fine in gnome terminal and in xterm. But they both open a bash shell when I start a new tmux session. When I open terminator it opens with this error `Unsupported use of '='. To run 'bash' with a modified environment, please use 'env TERM=xterm-256color bash…'
fish: TERM=xterm-256color bash -l`

I'm not to concerned with the terminator problem, and tmux opening a bash shell when opened from fish is a secondary issue. I bring them up in case they might point to the issue.

I'm concerned why termite is throwing an open terminal failed error when I try to invoke tmux. Any idea on how I can fix this or why its happening?

Ubuntu 16.04
Fish 2.2

Answer (score 4):

The bug.

```
( exec </dev/tty; TMUX= tmux )
```

The explanation. You need all 3 fds pointing to the TTY for tmux to work.

```
ls -la /proc/$$/fd; ( exec </dev/tty; ls -la /proc/$$/fd; TMUX= tmux )
```

A failed attempt at a fix. It's not good enough to point to the same tty.
&0, &1 and &2 must share a pointer to the tty.

```
export TTY=$(tty); ls -la /proc/$$/fd; ( exec </dev/tty; ls -la /proc/$$/fd; exec <$TTY; ls -la /proc/$$/fd; TMUX= tmux )
```

**The fix**. &1 still points to the same thing that &0 used to point to, so use it to resume.

```
( exec </dev/tty; exec <&1; TMUX= tmux )
```

Answer (score 1):

[This may be an off-topic answer, but this post is the first hit when I Googled "tmux /dev/tty error".]

I experienced a similar problem when accessing through SSH and found a "no-brainer" *solution* ==> to **restart** the SSH connection :) Here goes how I first arrived at the `/dev/tty` error:

- SSH access to a Ubuntu system,
- installed as Windows WSL on a Win-10 machine
- The SSH session is initialized by another WSL system on another Windows 10 machine, via ConEmu

I just got the SSH to work, and have just spent minutes on copying in my older settings into `~/.tmux.conf` and installing `fish + omf`.

---

### Initializing a new SSH session addressed all the concern for me.

Within the same SSH session, things were a bit off ==> I was prompted with the following error:

```
open terminal failed: can't use /dev/tty
```

However, without changing any specific setting, firing up a new "tab" in ConEmu and initializing another SSH session to the same destination machine have solved all the trouble. Not more `/dev/tty` error.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall tmux before installing omf fish. When you finish installing omf fish. Reinstall tmux. That worked for me!

Comment: I've just installed oh-my-fish and tried to launch tmux in the same fish session, I got the same error as OP. After opening a new fish session tmux launched without problems, I haven't done any special tmux reinstallations

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what `termite` gains you over `gnome-terminal`. `termite` has a "selection mode", but if you are running `tmux` inside `termite`, then `tmux` already has a similar selection mode you can use.  If you want to launch a different shell besides `bash` inside Tmux, see the Tmux `default-shell` configuration option.

The number one search result for [tmux termite](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux/issues/32) is about the problem they have working together.

The practical solution here seems to be to remove `termite` from the equation.

Comment: That issue is for neither tmux nor termite, but someone's pimped out tmux config (including all that powerline cruft). To conclude from that the problem is with termite is a long, and completely unjustified, jump.